# I have been developing a web app in django. But whenever i make any changes to the css, it doesnt get applied

Tags: html, css, django

I'm trying to create a web app using Django and encountered a problem. Whenever I make any changes to the css file, the webpage does not show these changes. However, if I copy the contents from that css file, create a new css file and paste it there, it works perfectly. I don't know what is happening, please help.

I am trying to change the css of to make some changes in the webpage but the changes are not getting applied. I have to create a new file and paste the contents from the previous css file if I want to make any changes. This new file works perfectly for some time, then it stops responding again - then I have to create a new css file.

Comment: Likely caching. Use Ctrl+F5 when refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this article https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

If you have done everything correctly, then after each change you need to use the command `python manage.py collectstatic`